# Upload photo on AWS w/ Python script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am writing a Python script that uploads photos from my computer to AWS.

I can get `policy, key, signature credentials` but cannot find information on AWS website the method to upload photo from my computer to AWS repository:

```
Location : https://myrepo.s3.amazonaws.com/folder1/1234.jpg

Request Method:POST
```

I think there is something with the `payload`.

(BTW this is my first post :-)

Comment: Did you look into Boto3? http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html#using-boto-3
If your authentication credentials are set, does the _# Upload a new file_ section helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the getting started article i found the example

```
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.create_bucket('media.yourdomain.com')  # bucket names must be unique
key = bucket.new_key('examples/first_file.csv')
key.set_contents_from_filename('/home/patrick/first_file.csv')
key.set_acl('public-read')
```

you can try to do the same way

P.S. more details [here](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/3998)

Comment: thanks but the problem is I only have policy, key, and signature credentials. I don't have aws_access_key_id = {ACCESS KEY ID}
aws_secret_access_key = {SECRET ACCESS KEY}

Comment: login to aws console account and generate them

Comment: I am just a user and can't have access to this. I just can deal with policy, key, and signature credentials :/

Comment: you write an application, right? then you should configure your backend to allow your users to upload files in your bucket, that's why you have to get access and secret keys and initialise your bucket uploader